# Java versus XML&Lua for storing voxel/block types

Tags: java, xml, class, lua, storage

So, I want it to be very easy to create all the entities of my game and for other people to come in and do the same. I was thinking I could just let the users/myself create an XML sheet the stores all the properties of each block (Like a Terraria or Minecraft voxel) and add Lua scripts that are referenced in the XML for additional functionality of any of the blocks.

I'm starting to think It would just be easier to let the user create a JAR file full of classes for each block. And then that JAR file could easily be used to get all the blocks. It'd just be interesting to reference all the blocks by a block id without storing all the classes by ID. Or I could give each class a static id. But that's not important.

Okay, so my short question is **what are the pros and cons of storing all the the different types of blocks as classes versus in an XML sheet with Lua for additional functionality?**

**UPDATE:** It looks like I'll be using pure Lua! Looks like an interesting and effective way to do it!

Comment: Why not just abandon XML entirely and just use Lua? Lua is also a good data-description language; there's no need to overcomplicate things with XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A limitation of the JAR approach is that your data would need to be compiled before it got used. With XML/Lua the data gets read/interpreted at runtime.

A third option that you did not mention is using straight Lua tables instead of XML. This lets you load the data with a simple "require", "dofile" or similar instead of needing to use a XML library as well.

Comment: I did not consider that. I've used Lua strictly in the past for scripting. Thanks so much!